# Insert Colon between each element of a list python

Tags: python

```
[x[1] for x in matches]
x
newtest = [x2[-2:] for x2 in x]
newtest
```

I have a list

```
[u'asvbsMasd', u'abdhesMrty', u'ahdksC', u'ahdeO', u'ahdnL', u'ahddsS',]
```

now i want my list to be like a colon between where it finds a lower case and upper case

```
[u'asvbs:Masd', u'abdhes:Mrty', u'ahdks:C', u'ahde:Oqqq', u'ahdn:L', u'ahdds:S',]
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation of what you want to achieve and what you have tried here. It is not clear at all. See the guidelines for asking a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide more explanation, and what you tried with a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have a list [u'asvbsMasd', u'abdhesMrty', u'ahdksC', u'ahdeO', u'ahdnL', u'ahddsS',]  now i want my list to be like a colon between where it finds a lower case and upper case [u'asvbs:Masd', u'abdhes:Mrty', u'ahdks:C', u'ahde:Oqqq', u'ahdn:L', u'ahdds:S',]

Comment: First figure out how to do this with one string. Wrap that in a function, and then apply to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a regex that matches *<lowercase><uppercase>* pair:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'([a-z])([A-Z])')
```

Note the letters itself marked as a groups via `()`. If you have regex matching the pair and the neighbor letters as two separate groups, you may just use the substitution (`\1` and `\2` are places where matched groups are put into the substitution string):

```
>>> r.sub(r'\1:\2', u'asvbsMasd')
u'asvbs:Masd'
```

Then you can use list comprehension to apply that substitution to each element of a list:

```
>>> l = [u'asvbsMasd', u'abdhesMrty', u'ahdksC', u'ahdeO', u'ahdnL', u'ahddsS']
>>> [r.sub(r'\1:\2', s) for s in l]
[u'asvbs:Masd', u'abdhes:Mrty', u'ahdks:C', u'ahde:O', u'ahdn:L', u'ahdds:S']
```

Or if you want it wrapped into a function:

```
import re

re_lowerupper = r = re.compile(r'([a-z])([A-Z])')

def add_colons(l):
    global re_lowerupper
    return [re_lowerupper.sub(r'\1:\2', s) for s in l]

print add_colons([u'asvbsMasd', u'abdhesMrty', u'ahdksC', u'ahdeO', u'ahdnL', u'ahddsS'])
```

You may of course simplify it just to a single lambda, like in the next example.

One importand disclaimer, as I see you use Unicode strings: there is no easy way of finding *arbitrary* Unicode upper/lowercase character. There is no shorthand defined like for matching any digit (`\d`) or any alphanumeric character (`\w`). If you need to match diacritics too, you may need to list the lowercase and uppercase diacritics of your language explicitly in the regex, like:

```
re_lower = ur'[a-zßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýþÿāăąćĉčēĕėęěğģĥĩīĭįĵķļľŀłņňŋōŏőœŕŗřśŝşţťũūŭůűųŵŷźžǎǐǒǔǖǘǚǜǩǫǵǹȟȧȩȯȳəḅḋḍḑḟḡḣḥḧḩḱḳṃṕṗṙṛṡṣṫṭṽẁẃẅẇẉẍẏẑẓẗẘẙạẹẽịọụỳỵỹ]'
re_upper = ur'[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝÞĀĂĄĆĈČĒĔĖĘĚĞĢĤĨĪĬĮİĴĶĻĽĿŁŅŇŊŌŎŐŒŔŖŘŚŜŞŢŤŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸŹŽƏǍǏǑǓǕǗǙǛǨǪǴǸȞȦȨȮȲḄḊḌḐḞḠḢḤḦḨḰḲṂṔṖṘṚṠṢṪṬṼẀẂẄẆẈẌẎẐẒẠẸẼỊỌỤỲỴỸ]'
re_lowerupper = re.compile('(%s)(%s)' % (re_lower, re_upper))
add_colons = lambda l: [re_lowerupper.sub(r'\1:\2', s) for s in l]
```

This should do the job for the Latin script European languages.